# cross-browser way of getting navigator.{browserLanguage, systemLanguage, userLanguage}

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is

```
var b = navigator.browserLanguage;
var sy = navigator.systemLanguage;
var u = navigator.userLanguage;
```

cross-browser and safe? Does JQuery have a better way of doing it?

One side question:-
What is safe?

```
 obj == null
 obj === null
```

-Ajay

Answer (score 2):

None of those three work in Chrome, for example, but `navigator.language` does. In my case it returns `en-US`.

As to the second part of your question, both of those are "safe" in that they won't throw exceptions, but they don't have the same behavior: `==` will do type casting (i.e. `0 == ""` is `true`), but `===` does not (i.e. `0 === ""` is `false`). Generally `===` is less likely to introduce subtle bugs, so might be considered safer.